# can a ceiling fan be wired via a 3-pin plug and switched using the standard power socket switch?

Tags: electrical

I've got a perfectly good ceiling fan without controller that I want to rig up in my shed for cooling purposes and wondered if there are any problems attaching a 3 pin plug to feed the power directly to it? Expecting to be able to control (turn it on/off) using the standard wall socket switch with the option of removing the plug from the wall socket whenever I wish to completely isolate it.

Comment: Why would you wish to isolate it?

Comment: how do you plan to *mount* this ceiling fan?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A ceiling fan swag kit is made, that allows you to convert a hardwired fan into a plug-in fan. You would install this kit, then install the outlet that is wired to the switch.